# Parallax Scroll Animation Choppy in IE, Yet Smooth in Chrome and Firefox. Issue with my code, or IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, parallax

Here is the code I am using for my parallax scroll. Basically, it's very smooth and has the intended effect in Chrome and Firefox, but very choppy in IE. Is this a common issue for IE, or could my code be better?

HTML

```
<div id="parallaxLayer1">
        <div class="layer1">

        </div>


</div>
<div id="parallaxLayer2" align="center">
        <div class="layer2"></div>
</div>
<div id="parallaxLayer3"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
parallaxScroll();
});

function parallaxScroll(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('#parallaxLayer1').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.5))+'px');
$('#parallaxLayer2').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.5))+'px');
$('#parallaxLayer3').css('top',(0-(scrolled*.75))+'px');
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
#parallaxLayer1 {
z-index:1;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

#parallaxLayer2 {
z-index:2;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

#parallaxLayer3 {
z-index:3;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE? The older ones are awfully slow compared to today's JS and layout engines

Comment: IE 11 (Edge, I guess?) The issue seems to persist in 10 and 9 as well. Haven't checked back to 8.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I use to fix the jerkyness in IE11 on win8 with fixed elements on scroll. It has smooth scroll on by default.

Let me know if this works for you.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
    $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var wd = event.wheelDelta;
        var csp = window.pageYOffset;
        window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
    });
}
```